# Как обособить значения строкового массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть строковый массив из 7 значений. При вводе числа система выдаёт день недели. Как обособить числа меньше 0 и больше 7, чтобы вывод был "Такого дня недели не существует".

```java
String weekDay[] = {"Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник",
        "Среда","Четверг", "Пятница","Суббота"};
System.out.println(weekDay[x%7]);
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно собрать из массива карту `Map<Integer, String>` и получать день недели по номеру от `1` до `7` с помощью метода [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-). В случае, если такого дня недели не существует, можно использовать метод [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-), или допилить метод `get`:

```java
String[] weekDay = {"Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник",
        "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"};

Map<Integer, String> daysMap = new HashMap<>() {
    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        return super.getOrDefault(key, "Такого дня недели не существует");
    }
};

daysMap.putAll(IntStream.range(0, 7).boxed()
        // собираем из массива карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // ключ - число,
                // день недели от 1 до 7
                i -> i + 1,
                // значение - строка
                i -> weekDay[i])));

System.out.println(daysMap.get(1)); // Воскресенье
System.out.println(daysMap.get(3)); // Вторник
System.out.println(daysMap.get(8)); // Такого дня недели не существует
System.out.println(daysMap.get(-2));// Такого дня недели не существует
```

Comment: Вы правы можно и даже профессионально. Хотя я тогда бы дополнил еще одним методом в Интефейсе - банально, getDay(int), что бы скрыть реализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Олексій Моренець,все правильно написал только не дописал ELSEтам все работает ...

```
    if (x<0 || x>6) {
    System.out.println("Not Used");
} else {
    System.out.println(weekDay[x%7]);
}
```

можно проще - тернарным оператором