# Взять из всех строк символ до точки и занести в лист

Tags: java, строки, list, arraylist, java-stream

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1. Текст1");
list.add("2. Текст2. продолжение текста");
list.add("3. Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст");
```

Нужно создать отдельный список `List<Long> id`, в котором будут номера по порядку с каждой строчки.

Можно ли сделать это через stream API? Вроде:

```java
List<Long> id = list.stream.map(i -> i.split("\\.")
```

...вот дальше не пойму как...

Answer (score 0):

Можно.

Попробуйте:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1. Текст1");
list.add("2. Текст2. продолжение текста");
list.add("3. Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст");

List<Long> ids = list
        .stream()
        .map(i -> Long.valueOf(i.split("\\.")[0]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(ids);
// [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно без регулярных выражений обойтись, с помощью метода [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("1. Текст1");
strings.add("2. Текст2. продолжение текста");
strings.add("3. Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст");

List<Long> longs = strings.stream()
        // выбираем подстроку с начала
        // строки до первой точки
        .map(e -> e.substring(0, e.indexOf('.')))
        // преобразовываем String в Long
        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf).boxed()
        // собираем в лист
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(longs); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Или можно одним [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) обойтись:

```java
List<Long> longs = strings.stream()
        // преобразовываем в Long подстроку
        // с начала строки до первой точки
        .map(e -> Long.parseLong(e.substring(0, e.indexOf('.'))))
        // собираем в лист
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, поскольку первый символ - это число, то можно собрать из листа карту `Map<Integer, String>`:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1. Текст1");
list.add("2. Текст2. продолжение текста");
list.add("3. Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст");

Map<Integer, String> map = list.stream()
        // собираем из листа карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // ключ - число, подстрока до первой точки
                e -> Integer.parseInt(e.substring(0, e.indexOf('.'))),
                // значение - подстрока от точки
                e -> e.substring(e.indexOf('.') + 1)));

// обходим карту и выводим результат
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));
```

Вывод:

```yaml
1: Текст1
2: Текст2. продолжение текста
3: Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст
```

---

См. дополнительно:

- [Как обособить значения строкового массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214018/419011)
- [Группировка нескольких полей в Stream API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213908/419011)