# Группировка нескольких полей в Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Для группировки и подсчета суммы использую конструкцию:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 3, 2));
        list.add(new SomeClass("AnotherOne", 4, 6));
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 1, 4));

        Map<String, Integer> someones = list.stream()
                // собираем из листа карту
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        // ключ - строка
                        e -> e.name,
                        // значение - число,
                        // суммируем два поля
                        e -> e.field1 + e.field2,
                        // суммируем значения
                        // повторяющихся элементов
                        Integer::sum,
                        // имплементация карты
                        // с сортировкой элементов
                        // в порядке добавления
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

        System.out.println(someones); // {Someone=10, AnotherOne=10}
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomeClass {
    String name;
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public SomeClass(String name, int field1, int field2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

Как можно ответ привести к виду `[SomeClass ("Someone", field1 = 4, field2 =6), SomeClass("AnotherOne", field1 = 4 , field2 = 6)]` , то есть суммировать `field1` и `field1` с общим `name` группировать по `name` и выдавать в `List`.

Comment: Это уже будет нестандартный мап.

Comment: Где происходит группировка?

Comment: @Roman C Я так понял, по `name` и одновременно суммируются отдельно `field1` и `field2`

Comment: @Максим посмотрите сюда https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector, вроде бы в конце есть то, что вам надо

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отдельно просуммировать значения полей класса, нужно из листа собирать `Map<String, SomeClass>`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 3, 2));
    list.add(new SomeClass("AnotherOne", 4, 6));
    list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 1, 4));

    Map<String, SomeClass> someones = list.stream()
            // собираем из листа карту
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    // ключ - строка
                    e -> e.name,
                    // значение - элемент,
                    // объект SomeClass
                    e -> e,
                    // суммируем значения полей
                    // повторяющихся элементов
                    (e1, e2) -> {
                        e1.field1 += e2.field1;
                        e1.field2 += e2.field2;
                        return e1;
                    },
                    // имплементация карты
                    // с сортировкой элементов
                    // в порядке добавления
                    LinkedHashMap::new));

    System.out.println(someones);
    // {Someone={field1=4, field2=6}, AnotherOne={field1=4, field2=6}}
}
```

В классе `SomeClass` нужно переопределить метод `toString`:

```java
class SomeClass {
    String name;
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public SomeClass(String name, int field1, int field2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{field1=" + field1 + ", field2=" + field2 + '}';
    }
}
```